# Vue: How to: pass a different handler to the @click event for the same component?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

I have a simple Vue component that renders a **territory** object.
It works fine and has the following `:to="{ name: 'TerritoryContactList', params: { id: territory.id }}"` in order to change the route.

Now, I have a new Parent component and need to use the same component but prevent it to go to a new route. Instead, I want to implement a `@click(handler)`.

What is the best practice in this case?

```
  <v-list-tile :to="{ name: 'TerritoryContactList', params: { id: territory.id }}" avatar>
    <v-list-tile-avatar color="amber" style="margin-right:3px">
      <v-icon color="white">map</v-icon>
    </v-list-tile-avatar>
    <v-list-tile-content>
      <v-list-tile-title v-html="territory.name"></v-list-tile-title>
        <v-list-tile-sub-title>{{territory.region.name}}</v-list-tile-sub-title>
    </v-list-tile-content>
    <v-list-tile-action>
      <v-list-tile-action-text>{{territory.address_count}}</v-list-tile-action-text>
    </v-list-tile-action>
  </v-list-tile>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make your components works fine in different situation,i suggest the click event in the componen be handled outside the component:

1.emit the event when user click the component:

```
<v-list-tile @click="this.$emit('clickListTile')" avatar>

  </v-list-tile>
```

2.handle the event in your parent component:

```
<your-component @clickListTile="doSomething"></your-component>
```

Comment: Awesome heads up! Thank you very much!

Comment: @JonathanMachado my pleasure to help :)